# to get sum in multiple conditions in mongodb and php

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've the following code to get the some of all price that have type `1` or a specific value but it dosen't work.

```
<?php
$m = new Mongo(); 
if (!$m)echo "Not Connected to database successfully";
$db =$m->mongo_project;
$collection = $db->prices;
$pipeline=array(
    array(
        '$match' => array(
            '_id' => array(
                '$type' =>1
            )
         )
    ),
    array(
        '$group' => array(
             '_id' => '',
             'count' => array(
                 '$sum' => '$price' 
             )
         )
    ),  
);
$out = $collection->aggregate($pipeline);
foreach ($out as $key=>$value) {
    if($key=='result') {
        $r=$value[0]['count'];
    }
}
echo $r;?>
```

Comment: You might want to add one or more example documents, the "specific value" you mentioned and the expected result to get useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean a document that has a field "type" with a value of 1. The [**`$type`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) operator used here is a special MongoDB operator used to match certain BSON types. In this case you were asking for matching `_id` fields that were a "DOUBLE" type, or BSON type 1.

Correcting this:

```
$pipeline=array(
    array(
        '$match' => array(
            'type' => 1
         )
    ),
    array(
        '$group' => array(
             '_id' => '',
             'total' => array(
                 '$sum' => '$price' 
             )
         )
    ),  
);
```

Or you could just get the "sum" of the "price" values per each "type" value by passing that as the `_id` in your [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) operation, instead. That way you can see everything at a glance:

```
$pipeline=array(
    array(
        '$group' => array(
             '_id' => '$type',
             'total' => array(
                 '$sum' => '$price' 
             )
         )
    ),  
);
```

In that context, '$type` means the value of the field.